# how can change offline to online at openfire presence?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I'm creating a messenger using XMPP.
I did connect to openfire server successfully.

Console log also received 'connecting' and 'connected' status, but I checked session on openfire admin console:

Name : Anonymous
Resource : some values
Node : Local
Status : Authenticated
Presence : Offline

If I use spark client program, it changed presence to Online status.

How can I change that?
Should I add more code to lines?

```
var jid = 'id';
var pw = 'testpw';
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/';
var connection = null;

connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
connection.connect(jid, pw, callback);

function callback(status){
    console.log(status);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To declare your Presence Status you have to add these lines in the callback function:

```
if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
    connection.send($pres());
}
```

If you need a web client example based on XMPP (using Strophe.js) check my Plunker below:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EhQHDsYpDhrECmaaIlZO

Comment: Thanks beaver. I checked presence from openfire admin console after added connection.send($pres()) code to line. But presence status still offline..and console.log are connecting is over. If use not connection.send($pres()). console.log are connecting and connected

Comment: But have you tried my client from Plunker (adapting it to your Openfire configuration)?

Comment: I tried now. It works great!!. I will find problem of my code. Thanks beaver :)

Answer (score 0):

Added send($pres())

```
if(status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED){
    connection.send($pres());
    console.log('connected');
}
```

[image]

Just can see connecting

And not added send($pres())

```
if(status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED){
    console.log('connected');
}
```

[image]

can see connecting and connected log